# Connect to existing Remote Desktop session when username is already logged in

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003

On some Remote Desktop servers, when two people login with the same username, it creates two sessions.

On other Remote Desktop servers, it kicks the first person off, and the second person takes over the session.

**Where is the setting to determine this behavior?**

We are trying to setup a server so that each user only has 1 session, but they end up logging into another session occasionally when they have network issues.

We use multiple servers, some are 2003, some are 2008, would be nice to know if the way this was configured differs on each as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in 2003 server, go to run -> enter tscc.msc and in the terminal server configuration mmc go to server settings and (un)check 'restrict each user to one session' depending if you want to allow/restrict more than one session per user.